# Formatting MS Access Form

Tags: ms-access

I would like the form data to be aligned horizontally instead of vertically.
Here is the snapshot of form that is currently displayed.

[image]

I would like to change this so that it looks something like this:

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Subject    | 56-020 | 56-020 | 56-020 | 56-020 | 56-020 |
| TargetDays | .      | 0      | 1      | 2      | 6      |
| MAP        | 80     | 67     | 84     | 73     | 85     |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

How to change the alignment so that column headers are showed as row headers and their corresponding values are display horizontally instead of vertically?

---

Thank you guys for the replies and suggestions 
@CPerkins

So far I have generated this query

```
TRANSFORM First(VITALS.MAP) AS FirstOfMAP
SELECT VITALS.Subject
FROM VITALS
GROUP BY VITALS.Subject
ORDER BY Val(VITALS.TargetDays)
PIVOT VITALS.TargetDays;
```

This produces result like this

```
Subject _   0   1   13  2   20  28  6   9
22-001  82  75  102 .   80  .   .   89  83
24-002  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
Subject _   0   1   13  2   20  28  6   9
25-001  .   .                           
27-001  110 63  87  .   92  .   .   124 96
```

It gives results for all subjects. Subject is Row heading and Target days are displayed as column names and corresponding MAP values as values. I have a couple of questions with this.

1. I would like to sort the column values 
   For example, currently it is shown as

   Subject      _      0      1      13      2      20      28      6      9

I want it to be shown as

```
Subject      _      0      1      2      6      9      13      20      28
```

2. I want to get the result per subject. I don't want all subjects at a time to be shown.
   Also is it possible to hide Subject (which is Row heading)?

Please tell me how this can be accomplished?

Thank you.

P.S: Some one was telling that we can use auxiliary tables for transposing table just like matrix. Does any one have an idea how this can be done? On googling I found no comprehensible source for this concept.

Comment: Is the form currently set up to display in continuous mode (meaning that multiple records are being displayed in your screenshot)?

Comment: Not possible, as all "headers" are equal.

Comment: @Gustav  Perhaps not possible with standard SQL transforms exactly as shown, but perhaps the Subject and TargetDays are meant to be a composite "key" (i.e. column head) which could be formatted differently.  Regardless, if the displayed format is absolutely necessary, an auxiliary table could be created, populated and reported.  It'd take multiple steps, maybe some VBA, but it can be done.

Comment: @CPerkins: Right. I should have appended: _.. as is._

Comment: @KenWhite This is not a duplicate of Pivot. I don't think I am asking about Pivoting. I just want to reverse the alignment of form so that the values are shown horizontally instead of vertically. I mean, Just rotate the form 90 degrees anti-clockwise. Please help in this regard.

Comment: @CPerkins Please kindly elaborate on how this can be accomplished as you mentioned VBA etc.. Could you please give me some more clue with a sample code?

Comment: @KenWhite But a pivot table, accomplished in Accessing using the SQL TRANSFORM...PIVOT statement and called a crosstab query in Access (answered in the link  you shared), is usually for aggregate data, and **the column headers are not automatically listed as row headers.**  sam is asking for a pure matrix transform or simply changing the orientation of how the report is displayed.  This could also be called a "pivot", but the particulars of the results differ and it is these details that need answering.

Comment: @CPerkins: I retracted my close vote, based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Terms:** Because this question involves transforming rows into columns and columns into rows--including intermediate structures and logic, detailed descriptions can become confusing.  I will use the term **record** to refer to the source table/query row and the term **field** to refer to corresponding columns.  These are already common terms used when discussing relational databases, but I specifically use these terms separate from their context as horizontal or vertical, rows or columns.  Any use of the terms **row** or **column** are intentional and imply context of a specific table or query.

---

Access does not support native horizontal reports with headers on the right and data records automatically listing from left to right.  As pointed out in comments, the crosstab query (or pivot table) is meant for aggregate data and it *does not produce* a fully horizontal version of the default report, with all table columns & rows along with their headers being transformed.

An alternative is to place the transformed data into a separate auxiliary table and then produce a report with the auxiliary table as its RecordSource.  Appropriate formatting in the Report designer can be applied to simulate horizontal headers, etc.

**Caveat**: This technique is only a useful workaround for producing short horizontal reports with limited records, especially useful for sub-reports.  This technique will not produce full horizontal reports that span multiple pages, nor with automatically-sized columns, and other functionality available for built-in vertical report behavior.  (If you're clever, perhaps you could develop multi-page reports, but if that's necessary you should probably consider an alternative, maybe a 3rd-party report generation utility.)

1. Create an auxiliary table.

   - Define a column called `[field_header]`.  Specify that is should be required.
   - Define columns for each transformed *record* of the source query.

     - Since the record order should be flexible, just name them sequencially, e.g. `[Record001]`, `[Record002]`, ...
     - Caveats are already notes, so realize that you will need some way of choosing a limited number of records.  (If records are excluded, you should probably have some way of noting this on the report.)
     - The data type will likely need to be Text, since it will be storing *formatted values of varying data types*.  Only if every field in the data set has the same type should you choose that specific data type.
     - Make these columns "Not required" (i.e. nullable) so that you can populate the records in the most efficient way, especially since each table row will consist of data from multiple source records.
2. Populate the auxiliary table.

   - For each source field:

     - Add a new auxiliary row and assign the field name/caption to the auxillary table `[field_header]` column value.
     - Query the source field in a **particular order**.  This order should match for each row that is added to the auxillary table so that source records are not mixed up.  This order could be implicitly maintained if, for instance, a single sorted recordset were obtained and enumerated repeatedly rather than requerying the source each time.
     - For the same source field, repeatedly read the source field value and place it into the corresponding auxillary table column value.  The source value should be formatted to text however it should appear on the actual report.  You will not be able to use all of the report designers various formatting options.  Example:  A currency value of -4.95 should be converted to text in an appropriate format like "($  4.95)".
3. Create a report with the auxillary table as the RecordSource.

   - Add the table columns to the report.
   - Format the column for `[field_header]` with a distinct header format.  Perhaps add a vertical line or whatever to distinguish it as the header.

This entire process should likely be done in Visual Basic (VBA) functions.  By its nature, such code supports numerous ways to do this, perhaps by generating and executing SQL statements, or using DAO recordset and Access Automation objects for table definitions, etc.  Alternative programming objects are "Microsoft ActiveX Data Ojects" and "Microsoft ADO Ext. for DDL...".

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you are in layout view.  If you switch to design view you can place the design controls in any orientation you want.  They can be dragged around the interface and oriented as you see fit.  Reply in the comments if you have specific questions about using the interface.

Another note is that you may have "layouts" assigned to those controls.  You'll need to select them all with a drag click or by clicking the + in the top right corner of the group, right click one of the controls in the group, go down to layout and click "remove layout".  This allows the controls to be moved independently of one another.

One last thing, and this is just preference, but I generally like to set them as "popups" so that they appear in a new window.  I find it makes the fit more true to what I had in mind while designing the form.  Just my 2 cents.  This can be found in the "Other" tab of the form properties.

Comment: No, this is not simply a report "layout" issue since the OP is asking to transform the data... making the rows into columns (and vice versa).

Comment: This is not a report or page layout issue. Read the question again.